# c# excel interop performance loading data

Tags: c#, excel-interop, excel-addins

I have an excel interop project that is being runned from a ribbon. My issue is that when loading data of 64k with 30 columns it is insanely slow. So I created another set of projects, one project that creates and launches an excel sheet from winforms window via button click and loads 100k rows just fine, the other project is an excel add in project created from visual studio. Loading data in the add in is incredibly slow. from examing it while loading rows which is done by creating a range on the sheet and setting 2 dimensional array to that range takes minutes bec there seems to be threads exiting during the process. Can anyone help me get clarity or a way to speed up the process. Thanks
Code to where I am setting value to the sheet:

```
public static Interop.Range AddData(DataTable dataTable, Interop.Worksheet sheetToAddTo, int rowOffset) {
        Interop.Range tableRange = sheetToAddTo.Range[sheetToAddTo.Cells[1 + rowOffset, 1], sheetToAddTo.Cells[1 + rowOffset, 1]];
        if (dataTable != null && dataTable.Columns.Count > 0)
        {
            //create the object to store the column names
            object[,] columnNames;
            columnNames = new object[1, dataTable.Columns.Count];

            //add the columns names from the datatable
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                columnNames[0, i] = dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;

            //get a range object that the columns will be added to
            Interop.Range columnsNamesRange = (Interop.Range)sheetToAddTo.Range[sheetToAddTo.Cells[1 + rowOffset, 1], sheetToAddTo.Cells[1 + rowOffset, dataTable.Columns.Count]];

            //a simple assignement allows the data to be transferred quickly
            columnsNamesRange.Value2 = columnNames;

            //release the columsn range object now it is finished with
            columnsNamesRange = null;

            if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //create the object to store the dataTable data
                object[,] rowData;
                rowData = new object[dataTable.Rows.Count, dataTable.Columns.Count];

                //insert the data into the object[,]
                for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dataTable.Rows.Count; iRow++)
                    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < dataTable.Columns.Count; iCol++)
                        rowData[iRow, iCol] = dataTable.Rows[iRow][iCol];

                //get a range to add the table data into 
                //it is one row down to avoid the previously added columns
                Interop.Range dataCells = (Interop.Range)sheetToAddTo.Range[sheetToAddTo.Cells[2 + rowOffset, 1], sheetToAddTo.Cells[dataTable.Rows.Count + rowOffset + 1, dataTable.Columns.Count]];

                //assign data to worksheet
                dataCells.Value2 = rowData;

                //release range
                dataCells = null;
            }

            //return the range to the new data
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                tableRange = sheetToAddTo.Range[sheetToAddTo.Cells[1 + rowOffset, 1], sheetToAddTo.Cells[dataTable.Rows.Count + rowOffset + 1, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
            else
                tableRange = sheetToAddTo.Range[sheetToAddTo.Cells[1 + rowOffset, 1], sheetToAddTo.Cells[1 + rowOffset + 1, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
        }
        return tableRange;
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely no clue why it would be slow without seeing your code. Have you been able to identify any particular pain points in the code that take an inordinate amount of time?

Comment: From my experience, Interop is insanely slow. Try optimizing your App to keep the number of calls through Interop boundary as few as possible. I.e. copy and paste data into big ranges rather than individual cells. I eventually gave up on Interop and switched to ACE.OleDB.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times, this is an issue with interop calls.

You shouldn't do this:

```
for (int col = 0; col < 30 ; col++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 30 ; row++)
    {
        object theValue = range.Cells[row,col].Value;
    }
}
```

but:

```
object[,] allValues = range.Value;
```

This increases performance a lot.

Comment: In that case it is almost the same. Create a multidimensional array (so object[,]) and set the range.Value to it, also disable Calculation and calculate at the end.

Comment: im doingthat and for 10K rows from an add in its slow, I can send the code

Comment: I know from personal experience that this can be slow indeed. What is your current duration of the whole procedure ex database time?

Comment: just to load 65450 rows of data which spans 30 col i timed it at 53289 ms